# Exclude all tags from facet in Solr

Tags: solr, facet, solr-search

At the moment I am trying

```
json.facet={
  "category" : { "type": "terms", "field": "category" },
  "initial_category" : { "type": "terms", "field": "category", domain: { excludeTags: "*"} }
}
```

But no success.

I need for `initial_category` to retrieve buckets without all filters.

The complete query is

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/items/query -d '
q=name:phone&
fq={!tag=size}size:2XL&
rows=0&
json.facet={
  "category" : { "type": "terms", "field": "category"},
  "initial_category" : { "type": "terms", "field": "category", domain: { excludeTags: ""} }
}'
```

How to exclude all tags from facet?

Comment: What is your complete query? You'll have to tag the filters appropriately as well

Comment: @MatsLindh I've updated the question

Comment: From what I can see there is no wildcard support for `excludeTags` (and in your complete query, there is no `*` present). `excludeTags: "size"` should do what you want.

Comment: In this case yes, but I can have multiple tags in the query, so I am looking for a solution to not mention all of them, but to specify something like wildcard

Comment: There is no wildcard support as far as I can see, so you'll have to mention each one as a list - `excludeTags: "size,color,etc"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like:

```
json.facet={
  "category": {
    "type": "terms",
    "field": "category"
  },
  "initial_category": {
    "type": "terms",
    "field": "category",
    domain: {
      query: "*:*"
    }
  }
}
```

facet.domain.query allows to run a facet over an arbitrary query regardless of the main domain.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/json-faceting-domain-changes.html#arbitrary-domain-query